# How to get url of page in Liquid (Jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I am writing documentation with Github pages (Jekyll) and in one page I want to make link to another. I tried to use `{% page_url post-name %}` but with no luck. When I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` I get this exception:

```
Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of nil into String in docs/page1.md
```

My posts are in subdirectory `docs` and the structure of my documentation looks like this:

```
CNAME
_config.yml
_includes/
_layouts/
_site/
css/
docs/
   page1.md
   page2.md
   page3.md
imgs/
js/
index.md
```

The configuration file contains:

```
safe: true
lsi: false
pygments: true
markdown: kramdown
```

All pages in `docs/` subdirectory contains YAML block:

```
---
layout: docs
title: Page Two
permalink: /docs/page2/
---
```

And now, I try to get page url of this `page2`:

```
{% page_url page2 %}
{% page_url docs/page2 %}
{% page_url /docs/page2/ %}
{% page_url /docs/page2.md/ %}
```

None of this works, I am still getting `Liquid Exception`.

So what is the proper way to get url of page in subdirectory?

Comment: You might try setting `docs: your site url` in your `_config.yml` file, then use `site.docs` concatenated with "page2" to get the page's URL. This is very ugly, tho--are you sure there isn't anything in [jekyll variables](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/) that you could use?

Answer (score 7):

use the generic link tag:
{% link _collection/name-of-document.md %}

so, something like
{% link docs/page2.md %}

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the `{% post_url %}' tag, eg:

```
{% post_url 2010-07-21-name-of-post %}
```

More details in Jekyll's docs: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#post-url